# Which are the standards for unitCode in schema.org for Tourism and Leisure Industry

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have a site that offers, for instance, Hotel rooms. The prices for this kind of offer is usually "given on the basis of 2 persons per night"; meaning the price showed is what each person pays given that he/she shares the room with another one.

Here a snippet of the code:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"
         itemid="urn:www.example.com:products/1">
    <p itemprop="name">Hotel La Moka</p>

    <section itemprop="offers"
             itemscope
             itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

        Price: 
        <span itemprop="price" itemscope
              itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
        From <span itemprop="minPrice">56</span>
             <meta itemprop="currency" content="EUR"> €
        On the basis of <span itemprop="billingIncrement">2</span>
        <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="WHAT??"> persons per night.</span>
    </section>
 </section>
```

As you see the unit "persons per night" is not actually given a unitCode. So the question is: Which is the UN/CEFACT code for this unit?

Comment: It seems that schema.org by itself and UN/CEFACT are inadecuate for this task. I have found http://ontologies.sti-innsbruck.at/acco/ns.html; for this use case. I'm studying it in order to decide if that's case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the schema.org/Hotel markup and for your prices, you could use the pricerange itemprop.  You could list other details and text such as "Prices based on double occupancy" outside of your schema tags.

Comment: schema.org/Hotel describes the Hotel as an Organisation, not the Logding services they might offer; what our site offers is the lodging and this is the Product (derived from ProductOrService of the GoodRelations ontology) we should describe, IMO. Currently I'm including that information as text; but I think a unitCode might help semantically, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For your information: I am the author of the ACCO extension for GoodRelations [1] , and I hope to turn it into an extension proposal for schema.org in the next months, so we would have a much better support for hotels etc. in schema.org.

[1] http://ontologies.sti-innsbruck.at/acco/ns.html